# Why is the variable not being accessed

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

Can't seem to figure out why its not able to access variable 'a':

```js
var a = function(){
    console.log('AAA');
}
(function(){
    console.log(a);
})();
```

Comment: Why isnt it?  ...

Comment: Your code is missing a semicolon after the value of `a`.

Comment: Add a semicolon. You're executing the first function and passing the second function as an argument. Then it throws an error when you try to invoke `undefined` since there's no return value.

Comment: One of the many quirks of JavaScript. Wasn't [the newline supposed to end the statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Basics)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're trying to call a function as follow `undefined()`, Why?

**This is what is happening:**

```
var a = function(){
    console.log('AAA');
}(...) //<- here you're calling the function `a`, but your function `a` doesn't return anything (`undefined`)
```

**You can solve this adding a semi-colon:**

```js
var a = function(){
    console.log('AAA');
}; //<- HERE!

(function(){
    console.log(a);
})();
```

Or, you can declare the function `a` as **Declaration** rather than as **Expression**

*Take at look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) to understand a little more.*

```js
function a(){
    console.log('AAA');
}

(function(){
    console.log(a);
})();
```

## Resource

- [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you build an IIFE. What that means is that:

```
 var a = function(){
    console.log('AAA');
}
()
```

Actually calls the function, and stores its result in a. If you put a function into that function call as an argument, it goes into nowhere as the first function accepts no parameter.

Comment: I would upvote because your answer explains the problem, but it's technically incorrect, saying `and stores its result in a`. The assignment is never reached since there's two chained invocations: `var a = function () { ... }(...)()` which is why the snippet in the question throws an error.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = function(){
    console.log('AAA');
};
(function(){
    console.log(a);
    a();
}());
```

Comment: An answer without an explanation is not an answer.